# Forcing a functor to map to a given set

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

Let $(X, \leq)$ be a poset and $J$ a small category. Let $S$ be a subset of $X$. Viewing $(X, \leq)$ as a category, does there exists a functor $F: J \rightarrow (X, \leq)$ such that $\{F(j)\}_{j \in \textrm{ob}(J)} = S$?

Comment: Of course not, for example it may happen that the cardinality of $ob(J)$ is smaller than the one of $S$. What motivates your question and what do you *really* want to ask?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what motivates this Question.  Certainly we need some consistency conditions.  If $|J|$ is less than $|S|$ it is not possible, and likely some compatibility restrictions on the arrows of $J$ with those of $X$ are necessary without being sufficient.

Comment: My motivation is that I'm trying to show that if $(X, \leq)$ contains a subset $S$ with no supremum, there is some functor $F:J \rightarrow (X, \leq)$ with no colimit. So I was trying to think of how to pick my functor.

Comment: Then, please edit your questiuon accordingly. Of course, one just takes $J=S$ then ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: My above comment was just the motivation for the post, but I actually wanted to ask the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this depends on what $J$ and $S$ are, for example if $\left|\operatorname{ob} J\right| < |S|$ then this is clearly impossible since $F$ can't be surjective on objects.

But even if $\left|\operatorname{ob} J\right| \ge |S|$ it is unreasonable to assume such a functor exists, in general.

For example, suppose $X$ has the discrete ordering ($x \le y \Rightarrow x=y$) and $J = (\mathbb{Z}, \le)$. A functor $J \to X$ is an order-preserving map of posets, so must be constant since $X$ is discrete, meaning that $\{F(j) : j \in \operatorname{ob} J\} = \{ x \}$ for some $x \in X$. So in this case no such $F$ exists for any $S \subseteq X$ of size $\ge 2$.

---

**Updated:** To answer your more specific question from the comments: suppose $S \subseteq X$, let $J = (S, \le)$ and let $F = \iota : S \hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion functor. Then $\operatorname{colim} F$, if it exists, is equal to $\sup S$, as you can check from the definitions.